# jquery append not working but working in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-ajax

So.. I have 2 jquery functions that append something to a table.
the first one doesn't work , the second function does work? while in the first function my HTML var is filled with the good information to append, it just doesn't append it??

```
function buildTable(data) {
   var html = "";
   $.each(data, function (key, value) {
       html += "<tr>";
       html += "<td><a class='delete'><i class='fa fa-thrash'></i></a></td>";
       html += "<td class='key'>" + key + "</td>";
       html += "<td class='val'>" + value + "</td>";
       html += "<td></td>";
       html += "</tr>";
       //$(".table > tbody").prepend(html);
       //$(".addrow").append(html);
       //$("#parameterTable > tbody").append(html);
   });
   $('.addrow').prepend(html);

   //$(".formTable ").prepend(html);

}
```

Second function (the one that does work)

```
function addNewParameter() {
   if(!added) {
       var html = "<tr>";
        html += "<td></td>";
        html += "<td><input type='text' class='parameter1' name='Parameter1'></td>";
        html += "<td><input type='text' class='parameter2' name='Parameter2'></td>";
        html += "<td><a class='save'><i class='fa fa-save'></i></a><a class='undoAdd'><i class='fa fa-undo'></i></a></td>";
        html += "</tr>";
        $(".addrow").append(html);
        added = true;
   } else {
       showWarning("u heeft al een parameter toegevoegd, sla deze eerst op.");

   }

}
```

The HTML where I need to append it

```
<table class="formTable table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="parameterTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-2"></td>
            <td class="col-md-4">
                Naam
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-4">
                Waarde
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="addrow">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have been struggling with this for a while, any help would be nice

Comment: You do `.prepend()` and `.append()`.

Comment: ye i tried both, they both dont work

Comment: I think your problem is that in the non-working case you're building up a *list* of container elements (the `<tr>` elements) to append (well, prepend). You'd probably be better off wrapping all those rows in a `<tbody>`, and then append the whole `<tbody>` after the existing one. (A table can have as many `<tbody>` elements as you want.)

Comment: Can you confirm there is something in "data"? Also, you're building a list - not a single html node to append//prepend. Try putting your prepend inside the loop and clear the html string each time.

Comment: Another approach that might work would be to give `.prepend()` or `.append()` an array of those `<tr>` elements. However in my experience appending rows to a table is something that older IE versions simply would not do, and the `<tbody>` wrapper method was the only thing that worked reliably for me.

Comment: html does get filled with : "<tr><td><a class='delete'><i class='fa fa-thrash'></i></a></td><td class='key'>..... ect "

Comment: so bassicly is does fill the html with the right html, thats not the problem , it just doesn't wanna put it in the tbody ( while i have the same thing in the second function)

Comment: I'm sure the HTML content *looks* OK; my point is that it's HTML for a *list* of elements and not a single one.

Comment: So you could try having that `html` variable be an array instead of a single string, and have each iteration of your `$.each()` build a single `<tr>` string and `.push()` that onto the array. Then, pass the array to `.append()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this?

```
function buildTable(data) {
       var html = "";
       $.each(data, function (key, value) {
           html += "<tr>";
           html += "<td><a class='delete'><i class='fa fa-thrash'></i></a></td>";
           html += "<td class='key'>" + key + "</td>";
           html += "<td class='val'>" + value + "</td>";
           html += "<td></td>";
           html += "</tr>";
       });
       $('.addrow').append(html);

    }
```

Comment: yep :( i did try this the html var is filled right, it just doesn't fill it

Answer (score 0):

Proper usage of jQuery does not require ending tags:

```
function addNewParameter() {
    if (!added) {
        var newHtml = $('<tr>');
        newHtml.append($('<td>'));
        newHtml.append(
            $('<td>').append(
                $('<input>'.addClass("parameter1").attr({"name":"Parameter1","type":"text"}))
                )
        );
        html.append(
            $('<td>').append(
                $('<input>').addClass("parameter2").attr({"name":"Parameter2","type":"text"})
            )
        );

        html.append(
            $('<td>').append(
                $('<a>').addClass('save').append(
                    $('<i>').addClass("fa fa-save")
                ),
                $('<a>').addClass('undoAdd').append(
                    $('<i>').addClass("fa fa-undo")
                    )
                )
            );
        $('.addrow').append(newHtml);
        added=true;
        }
        else {
        showWarning("u heeft al een parameter toegevoegd, sla deze eerst op.");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with a bootstrap dialog , after the dialog was loaded and then the append function it worked